# Posting data alternative to extract()

Tags: php, ajax

How can I post the data on my php side without using the extract().  I am not sure how to name it and assign it to a variable, specifically I think "act=like&pageID" is causing me the problem.

My JS is:

```
 $(function(){ 
        var pageID = <?php echo $pageID;  ?>; 
        var user_id = <?php echo $user_id;  ?>; 

        $('.like-btn').click(function(){
            $('.dislike-btn').removeClass('dislike-h');    
            $(this).addClass('like-h');
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"ajaxvoteitem.php",
                data:'act=like&pageID='+pageID+ '&user_id=' + user_id,
                success: function(){
                }
            });
        });
});
```

The code post works when I used the extract(), but I want to post it out the long way using individual variables.

I tried this with no luck:

ajaxvoteitem.php:

```
$pageID = $_POST['pageID'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Why do so many devs use the `$.ajax` `data` param the hard way? `data: { act: 'like', pageID: pageID, user_id: user_id }`

Comment: Please expand on *"tried this with no luck"*. What does that even mean? Can you see the correct data being sent via your browser's *Net* developer console?

Comment: Ajax Part is 100% correct must me error with some other part of code

Comment: Worked like a charm.  THanks Phil!  I have to wait 8 hours now to post what worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping a noob out Phil.  Worked like a charm!  Used: `data: { act: 'like', pageID: pageID, user_id: user_id },`

JS:

```
$(function(){ 
        var pageID = <?php echo $pageID;  ?>; 
        var user_id = <?php echo $user_id;  ?>; 

        $('.like-btn').click(function(){
            $('.dislike-btn').removeClass('dislike-h');    
            $(this).addClass('like-h');
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"ajaxvoteitem.php",
                data: { act: 'like', pageID: pageID, user_id: user_id },
                success: function(){
                }
            });
        });
});
```

ajaxvoteitem.php:

```
$act = $_POST['act'];   
$pageID = $_POST['pageID'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
```